# django database delta update

Tags: mysql, django-models

Say I want to perform the following:

"update main_post set votes = votes+1 where post_id = xxx"

Such delta update is needed to deal with concurrency issues. Or is there any alternative to solve this concurrency issue?

Does django in any way support delta update out of the box?

*** Answer ***
Use the F object in Django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the F object in Django. Refer to docs